# The code which i posted is I2s code | I'm having the same error in different lines,please help me out

Tags: vhdl

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    11:00:43 07/08/2014 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    i2s_3 - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
--use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity i2s_3 is
    generic (constant delay :time :=10 ns);
     Port ( sck : inout  STD_LOGIC;
           sd : out  STD_LOGIC;
           ws : inout  STD_LOGIC);
end i2s_3;

architecture Behavioral of i2s_3 is

signal clk :std_logic;
signal Shift_Register : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal PL,WSP:std_logic := '0';
signal WSD :std_logic;
signal Left_Reg,Right_Reg : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal inc,inc_1,starting :std_logic;

signal count : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal Bit_Count : integer range 0 to 9; 

type state_type is (ideal,start,transmit);
signal state,next_state : state_type;

begin
    clk <= not sck;
 process(state)
 begin
  case state is 
    when ideal =>
      if rising_edge (sck) then 
        next_state <= start;
        else 
        next_state <= ideal;
      end if;
    when start =>
     IF(ws = 0) then        --error LINE 67
       next_state <= transmit; inc <= '1' after delay;
     else 
        next_state <= transmit;  inc_1 <= '1' after delay;
    end if;
    when transmit =>
    if(Bit_Count /= 8) then starting <= '1'; 
    end if;

    when others => "XXXXXXXX";  --error LINE 76
    end case;
end process;

 process(sck,count)
 begin  
    if rising_edge(sck) then 
        state <= next_state ; count <= count + 1; end if; --error LINE 83
    if(count = 4) then PL <= '1'; end if; --error LINE 84

    if rising_edge (clk) then 
      if(inc = 1) and (PL = 1) then  --error LINE 87
        Shift_Register <= Left_Reg ; end if;
      if(inc_1 = 1) and (PL = 1) then 
        Shift_Register <= Right_Reg ; end if; --error LINE 89
    end if; 

    if(starting = 1) then 
       sd   <= Shift_Register & '0';    --error LINE 94
        Bit_Count <= Bit_Count + 1;     --error LINE 93
    end if;     

 end process;   
end Behavioral;
```

can anyone tell me what might be the error ? unable to decode it

```
Line 67: found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "="
Line 76: Type  void does not match with a string literal
Line 83: found '0' definitions of operator "+", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "+"
Line 84: found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "="
Line 87: found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "="
Line 89: found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "="
Line 94: found '0' definitions of operator "&", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "&"
```

Comment: How about posting just a small sample of the relevant signal definitions and one of the lines which is causing you problems.  People are unlikely to go wading through your code for you - you have to put some effort into minimising our effort

Comment: Sorry - I guess I wasn't so unlikely. :) At least the code had comments pointing directly to the lines that had the errors - made it pretty easy this time.

Comment: -1: Not reduced to a minimal testcase and will never help anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the numerous VHDL syntax errors fru1tbat chased down you seem to have over analyzed your design effort.  If you look at the I2S Bus Specification a transmitter doesn't have to know how many bits to transmit unless it's a master.  The number of bits is controlled by the duration of a baud (a '1' or a '0') on `WS`.  You're transmitter isn't a master (it doesn't drive `WS`).

If you look at Figure 5 (1986 Spec.):

[image: I2S Bus Specification Figure 5]

A transmitter can be oblivious to the number of bits in a channel transmission, using `WSD` (which you don't generate) to select between left and right channels, and using `WSP` to load the `Shift_Register`.  The D input to the Shift_Register is '0' which zero fills smaller than requested channel words.  Channel data longer than a `WS` baud is truncated by `WS` changing and creating a `WSP` pulse which loads the shift_register with the next channel word (selected by the state of `WSD`).

You can also use `falling_edge(sck)` and do away with a separate signal `clk`.`WS` high or low for the number of bits in the right or left channel (and they don't have to have the same number of bits).

All this means that you're state machine is overkill and the only place you need a counter is a master generating `WS` or a receiver (where a counter can be used to truncate precision a receiver can't use - MSB first transmission).

Should you decide you want an I2S Bus Master that is signifying by driving `WS`, it's simply high or low for the number of right or left channel bits clocked off `SCK`.

As fru1tbat notes in a comment you're not actually shifting `Shift_Register` in you present code, which would be clocked on the falling edge of `SCK`.

**addendum**

I sat down and wrote a model from Figure 5 shown above:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity i2s_transmitter is
    port (
        WS:     in  std_logic;  -- supplied by bus master
        SCK:    in  std_logic;  -- supplied by bus master
        SD:     out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of i2s_transmitter is
    -- left and write channel words, two's complement actually
    -- and should come from port interface
    -- also should be synchronous to SCK.
    signal DATA_LEFT:   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"CB"; -- dummy
    signal DATA_RIGHT:  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"97"; -- values

    signal WSD:         std_logic;
    signal WSD1:        std_logic; -- output of second delay FF nnamed.
    signal WSP:         std_logic;
    signal SHIFT_REGISTER:  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

begin

SR: 
    process (SCK)
    begin
        if falling_edge(SCK) then  -- SCK OVERBAR
            if WSP = '1' then      -- load left or right channel word
                if WSD = '0' then  -- mux for parallel load
                    SHIFT_REGISTER <=  DATA_LEFT;
                 else
                    SHIFT_REGISTER <= DATA_RIGHT;
                end if;
            else
                SHIFT_REGISTER <= SHIFT_REGISTER(6 downto 0) & '0';
            end if;  
        end if;
    end process;

    SD <= SHIFT_REGISTER(7);  -- MSB first, 7 downto 0 little endian

WSD_FF:    
    process (SCK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(SCK) then
            WSD <= WS;
        end if;
    end process;

WSD1_FF:    
    process (SCK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(SCK) then
            WSD1 <= WSD;
        end if;
    end process;  

WS_PULSE:
    WSP <= WSD xor WSD1;  

end architecture;
```

Also a quick and dirty test bench to verify it does the right thing:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity i2s_transmit_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of i2s_transmit_tb is

    signal WS:      std_logic := '0';
    signal SCK:     std_logic := '1';
    signal SD:      std_logic;

    constant clk_period:    Time := 400 ns;  -- 2.5 MHz typical
    constant ws_period:     Time := 16 * clk_period;

begin

DUT:
    entity work.i2s_transmitter
        port map (
            WS => WS,
            SCK => SCK,
            SD => SD
        );
CLOCK:

    process
    begin
        wait for clk_period/2;
        SCK <= not SCK;
        if Now > 30 * clk_period then  -- bound as a demo
            wait;  
        end if;
    end process;

STIMULUS:

    process
    begin
        wait for ws_period/2;
        WS <= not WS;

        if Now > 30 * clk_period then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Understanding the model is predicated on having the spec (see [I2S bus specification](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/I2SBUS.pdf))

Notice `SD` is invalid until the first shifted in '0' in `SHIFT_REGISTER` makes it to the output, lacking a reset. `WSD` and `WSD1` also show 'U' until valid data is presented on the rising edge of `SCK`.

This is a style of VHDL that behaviorally describes hardware taken from Figure 5 and gives us the result:

[image: i2s_transmit_tb]

This was done on OS X 10.9.4 using [ghdl-0.31](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/files/Builds/ghdl-0.31/) and [GTKWave](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I"m sorry, i'm new to VHDL and thanks @frut1bat and David Koontz, thanks for the effort which you guyes put in

Comment: I corrected the code and wrote it in Verilog, but in the simulation Model- sim i'm getting this message
ERROR: In process i2s_2.vCont_34_2 
 FATAL ERROR:ISim: This application has discovered an exceptional condition from which it cannot recover. Process will terminate

Comment: I think switching to Verilog was a bit drastic (and your error the basis for a question with the verilog tag).  You can't be missing too many concepts, and yes VHDL has a very particular syntax.  The secret here is to describe the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

**Line 67**: `ws` is type `std_logic`, which can be one of the following values: `'U'`, `'X'`, `'0'`, `'1'`, `'Z'`, `'W'`, `'L'`, `'H'`, or `'-'`. To compare using `=`, you need to put the single quotes around the value to identify it as a character literal. `0` (without single quotes) is an integer literal.

**Line 76**: `when others =>` then what? You're missing a statement here. Are you trying to compare to (others => `'X'`), or assign something a value of `"XXXXXXXX"`?

**Line 83/84**: With `numeric_std`, you can't add or compare numeric literals to `std_logic_vector` (nor should you want to, in my opinion). Change `count`'s type to `unsigned`, and you should be fine.

(By the way, you may want to think about adding line breaks there. Short code is nice and all, but I've found clarity is more helpful in the long run.)

**Line 87/89/93**: Same problem as Line 67.

**Line 94**: The basic problem here is that you're trying to assign an 8-bit vector (`Shift_Register & '0'`) to a signal of type `std_logic` (`sd`). You need to think about what you're trying to accomplish here. You will need to fix the syntax on that line, but you will also need to do something different with your logic as well.

Comment: you missed that 4 is out of range of count on line 87, which is currently `signal count: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);`  It's currently a two-bit counter.  The unlabeled process sensitive to state has both sequential and non-sequential assignments to next_state. The expression on line 94 is a length 9 array of type.  There's more wrong with the 'design'.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I missed some other things. I didn't try to compile or simulate the code myself, as the specific syntax errors in the question were pretty obvious. As to your second comment, there's more to it than just rewriting the assignment to `sd`, as `shift_register` is never actually shifted anywhere.